# CSS Hover Menu Problems

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my CSS hover menu.

It pops out perfectly fine and in the right location, however when I try to go to one of the options in the pop-out menu, it disappears and for the life of me I can't figure out how to stop it from doing so.

Is there any way to stop the menu from disappearing as soon as I try to select one of the sub menu options?

I've looked around on Stack Overflow (correct me if I'm wrong) and haven't found anything like this, but that may be because I have no idea how to search this problem properly.

I've tried using jQuery for this too, but I just had the same problem.

You can see a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j8Ny4/) which shows the problem perfectly.

Thanks.

Comment: You should get firebug and learn to use it. It's a great tool. getfirebug.com ..it will tell you the answers. The reason for the problem is very logical. The first level `li` (`:hover` element) and your second level `ul` (submenu element) have a gap between them. The gap is created by a big padding in the first level `ul`. ( Surely the little padding in the `.navigation` doesn't help. )

Comment: Hi Lollero, I have firebug - however I think I've been looking at the problem for so long that I've lost my direction and am just not thinking about it as I should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question actually.

I assigned a class to the `.navigation ul li:hover ul` called `.showup` and another which set the display of the `.navigaiton ul li ul` to none.

I then ran this jQuery to make it work

```
$('li:has(ul)').hoverIntent(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').removeClass('hide');
    $(this).find('ul').addClass('showup');
}, function() {
    $(this).find('ul').removeClass('showup');
    $(this).find('ul').addClass('hide');
})
```

and now it works great!

Answer (score 2):

I hope below link will help you

http://jsfiddle.net/j8Ny4/9/

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
li.sign {
    width: 80% !important;
}

.navigation ul li {
   width: 115%;
}
```

Comment: That makes it work if you go from the li to the first submenu option, but that wont necessarily fix the problem. People will hover over the option, see the popout menu and want to select something lower down if they want that, which means it will still disappear. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

give width -> .navigation ul accordingly

```
.navigation ul {
padding: 20px 20px 20px 40px;
list-style: none;
    width:300px; // according to your
}
```

Comment: Again, this relies on the pretence that somoene will go from `top level` -> `first option in the sub-menu`, which people will not do.